# При достижении 100 строк в CSV файле скрипт python остнавливается

Tags: python, pandas

у меня есть скрипт который парсит данные с базы данных по одному. Я хочу чтобы мой скрипт останавливался при достижении 100 строк в csv файле. Попробовал данным способом, но он не отработал.

```py
results = pd.read_csv('Created.csv')
N = len(results)
if N > 3:
    sys.exit()
```

Сам файл создается и наполняется данными в данной строке:

```py
with open('Created.csv', 'a', encoding = 'UTF-8') as f:
    f.write(f"{status_acc},{email},{password}\n")
```

Comment: Покажите results.info() что говорит

Comment: Пустота, могу ли я как watchdog запустить ваш отрезок кода с помощью субпроцесса?

Comment: @CrazyElf Пример
В main.py `subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'dog.py',])`

Comment: @CrazyElf Я думаю аргументы по записи прописать в данном отрезке. 
`with open('Created.csv', 'a', encoding = 'UTF-8') as f:
    f.write(f"{status_acc},{email},{password}\n")`
Чтобы не использовать pandas.

Answer (score 0):

```
if results.shape[0] > 100:
    sys.exit()
```

Размер датафрейма нужно проверять через shape - это свойство возвращает кортеж (число строк, число столбцов).

Comment: Код не отработал, скрипт дальше парсит данные.